# Django get_context( ) method. Does this exist?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have looked through the Django docs and search the code but cannot find any details for a function called get_context(). However, I have seen it used in a few spots in the code.

Is this a method that is available to use in Django or some internal method? I am not referring to get_context_data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a django form / widget class method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.get_context

https://github.com/django/django/search?p=2&q=get_context

Comment: The link to the docs is what I was looking for. Thank you. I was not finding this reference when I tried searching the docs myself.

Comment: I had to grep the source code and work back from there.